# Implementar Adword Conversion con AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, adword

Debo implementar en un proyecto desarrollado en AngularJs la conversión de Adword para saber cuándo una vista (vista.html) fue visitada.

Tengo el siguiente código que debo implementar pero no sé cómo hacerlo:

```
 goog_snippet_vars = function() {
   var w = window;
   w.google_conversion_id = 999999999;
   w.google_conversion_label = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
   w.google_remarketing_only = false;
 }

 // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
 goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
   goog_snippet_vars();
   window.google_conversion_format = "3";
   var opt = new Object();
   opt.onload_callback = function() {
   if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
     window.location = url;
   }
 }

 var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];

 if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
   conv_handler(opt);
 }

}

type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
```

Estuve viendo en muchos lugares pero la verdad estoy perdido.

Por favor si alguien me puede guiar como debo empezar estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: ¿Dónde conseguiste el código que acompaña a la pregunta?

Comment: Me lo pasaron, por lo poco que conozco del tema y lo que ví es código que te genera google adword para que lo implementes en tu página.

Comment: ¿Que sistema de ruteo estas usando `ui-router` o `locationProvider`?

Comment: $routeProvider y $location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay tres formas de lograr esto:

1. Usando una directiva:

   Esta solución implica que debes incluir la directiva en todas y cada una de tus vistas, lo cual es una solución ideal para cuando estás intentando solamente de rastrear algunas vistas no tu aplicación completa

   Primero incluyes el script de google en tu `index.html`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8">
   ```

   Luego incluyes una constante con todas las configuraciones de tu negocio

   ```
   angular.module('app')
       .constant('googleAdsSettings', {
                  google_conversion_id: 999999999, 
                  google_conversion_label: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                  google_remarketing_only: false
       });
   ```

   Luego declaras tu directiva de esta forma

   ```
   angular.module('app')
       .directive('trackPage', function($window, googleAdsSettings) {
           return {
               restrict: 'E',
               link: function() {
                   $window.google_trackConversion(googleAdsSettings);
               }
           };        
       });
   ```

   Esto hace que cada vez que se encuentre la directiva se ejecute una función que llama a la funcion `google_trackConversion` que viene incluida en el script de google que hará la conversión.

   **Demo:**

   ```js
   angular.module('app', [])

   angular.module('app')
     .constant('googleAdsSettings', {
       google_conversion_id: 999999999,
       google_conversion_label: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       google_remarketing_only: false
     });

   angular.module('app')
     .directive('trackPage', function($window, googleAdsSettings) {
       return {
         restrict: 'E',
         link: function() {
           $window.google_trackConversion(googleAdsSettings);
         }
       };
     });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <div ng-app="app">
     <track-page></track-page>
   </div>
   ```
2. Usando un factory:

   Esta solución es muy práctica cuando se quiere llamar desde un controller o desde un evento como por ejemplo el evento `$locationChangeSuccess` que se dispara cada vez que navegas hacia una página nueva ;). Sigues los mismos pasos que en la solución anterior pero en lugar de declarar una directiva.

   ```
   angular.module('app')
       .factory('trackPage', function($window, googleAdsSettings) {
           return function() {
               $window.google_trackConversion(googleAdsSettings);
           };
       })
       .run(function($rootScope, trackPage) {
           $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
               trackPage();
           })
       });
   ```

   Muy similar al anterior pero la llamada a la función está encapsulada en un factory y se ejecuta en el evento `$locationChangeSuccess` cuando la nueva vista ya ha sido mostrada
3. No usar angular en lo absoluto:

   ¿Qué? Pues si, recuerda que google incluye un `<noscript>` que contiene un tracking pixel para cuando javascript está desabilitado en la página  asi que puedes incluir este en cada una de tus vistas y funcionará de la misma forma que la directiva sin tener que escribir nada de código.

   Sólo debes quitar el tag `<noscript>` y usar el contentido directamente para que funcione (Recuerda que el tag `<noscript>` solo funciona cuando javascript está desabilitado).

   ```
   <div style="display:inline;">
       <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
           src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/999999999/?label=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
   </div>
   ```

   La parte mala de esta solución es que debes recordar pasarle todos los parámetros en el atributo `src` (o quizás hacer otra directiva para esto XD) por eso sólo te la recomiendo cuando quieras tracear una sóla página sin tener que escribir nada de código o como un reemplazo para la directiva de la primera solución.

Comment: Desde ya te agradezco tu respuesta, la cual estuve viendo y analizando, aunque hice un cambio el cual espero funcione.

Use la constante en mi controller, pero no use una directiva ni una factory. Pues necesito que el $window.google_trackConversion
se dispare o ejecute cuando doy click sobre un botón el cual ejecuta una funcion.

Ejemplo, tengo un <input type="buttom" on-click="ctrl.enviar();">

Espero funcione y ver el resultado mañana

Saludos

Comment: @EduardoMateoManeff Para eso estamos, para ayudar. Yo estructuré mi respuesta de acuerdo a la pregunta. En ella no pusiste que el tracking se hace al hacer click sino al entrar en las vistas. De todas formas la solución para angular siempre es más menos la misma y las puedes estructurar como quieras. El hecho que use un factory es para simplificar el código ya que generalmente se hace el tracking con la misma configuración asi que tener un factory que se encargue de los detalles me parecio un poco más limpio, pero es solo estetica, funcionalmente son equivalentes. Suerte.

Comment: @EduardoMateoManeff No te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió